# Mostrar valor de una caja de texto al pulsar Enter

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), el cual tiene una entrada de texto. Desde la misma entrada de texto si escribo, `20` y pulso <kbd>intro/⏎</kbd>, de igual manera para valores como `30` y `00`, quiero que me muestre lo siguiente: `302000`.

He probado muchas cosas pero no he conseguido nada.

Comment: Hola DriversDigital, bienvenido. Puedes mostrar el codigo que has intentado y explicar por que ese codigo no te funciona? Te da errores ? Donde quieres que te muestre el resultado?   Como está ahora, es muy amplia. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente intercepta el evento `keypress` y verifica si la tecla pulsada fue <kbd>intro</kbd>. Esto puedes hacerlo mediante [`KeyboardEvent#code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) o [`KeyboardEvent#key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). Antes se usaba [`KeyboardEvent#keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) pero **ha sido declarada obsoleta y será removida del estándar**, por lo que en un futuro próximo no existirá en los navegadores. Por lo pronto, **conviene usarla** ya que no todos los navegadores implementan el nuevo estándar para `code` y `key`.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function save(el, e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
    output.textContent += el.value;
    el.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeypress="save(this, event)"/>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta (+1) pero no deberias esperar a que el autor muestre qué ha intentado.. ?hay casos que el "he intentado" significa "no he hecho nada y me estoy tirando un farol" y le estarias haciendo la tarea y promoviendo ese tipo de preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Concuerdo contigo, pero no creo que esto sea "*hacer la tarea*" porque es una *duda* puntual. Si vas al sitio en inglés ves muchas de este tipo que tienen respuesta; se le explica cómo hacerlo sin tener en cuenta el posible objetivo final del OP.

Comment: @lois6b Como adición, aproveché la pregunta para añadir información adicional que considero importante, como el estado actual de `KeyboardEvent#keyCode` ya que no muchos están enterados y creo serviría para los visitantes.